# How to add Journals in Napili Template?

Tags: community, napili, articles

We are launching an Online Community Platform for one of our Company products.
We are planning to publish monthly Journals for our clients on the community specific to the product.
We are using Napili template and would really appreciate if someone could suggest a way to publish these journals on the community other than using Knowledge Base articles. 
We would also like to have a facility where user can read the journal, post comments about it and choose to like or dislike it.

Note: Journal might have quite rich content like high resolution images etc.

Comment: Chatter might work for you, but it has certain limitation like 99999 words or characters. How much content will be in journal

Comment: Using chatter will be a naive way of doing it. Moreover, chatter is more of a question/answer based style whereas journal is the information that the company wants to provide to its clients.